# Pyspark read column of jsons as rdd

Tags: json, postgresql, pyspark, loading, rdd

I was wondering what is the most performant (and correct) way to do this?

I have a postgres table containing multiple columns, one of which is a jsonb, and I want to load it into spark as an rdd.
Here is what I do

```
url = myPostgresURL
df = sqlContext.read.json(DataFrameReader(sqlContext).jdbc(
     url='jdbc:%s' % url, table='"myschema".mytable', properties=properties
     ).select('myjsoncolumn').rdd.map(lambda r: r.myjsoncolumn))
```

This works but is very slow (several minutes for 1M rows)

Thanks a lot.